# Scroll two recyclerView as one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two `Recyclerview` inside `NestedScrollView`. The second `Recyclerview` also have `SwipeRefreshLayout`. I try to set one scroll for both recycler, but my solution didn't work. Two recycler scroll separately and I don't have solution, please help my. Thanks in advance. My code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/noFriendsTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/no_friends_title"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarGetFriends"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainFriendsRelative"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/marginTopSmall"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/marginTopSmall"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paddingStart"
            android:id="@+id/lastConversationTitle"
            android:text="@string/friends_important_title"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lastChatFriendsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lastConversationTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopSmall"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paddingStart"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lastChatFriendsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopSmall"
            android:id="@+id/allFriendsTitle"
            android:text="@string/friends_all"/>
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/friendSwipeToRefresh"
            android:layout_below="@+id/allFriendsTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopSmall">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/friendsRecyclerView"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment code

```
private void setLastConversationFriendsRecycler(RecyclerView lastConversationRecyclerView, List<Edge<Friends>> friends){
    lastConversationList.addAll(friends);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    lastConversationRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lastConversationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    lastConversationAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), lastConversationList, lastConversationRecyclerView);
    lastConversationRecyclerView.setAdapter(lastConversationAdapter);
}

private void setFriendsRecycler(RecyclerView friendsRecyclerView, List<Edge<Friends>> friends){
    friendsList.addAll(friends);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    friendsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    friendsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    friendsAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), friendsList, friendsRecyclerView);
    friendsAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(friendsListener);
    friendsRecyclerView.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);
}
```

I also try different combination with `setNestedScrollingEnabled`, but result was the same.

Comment: Do you mean you have set setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) for both of your RecyclerViews?

Comment: Yes, When I set false for both recycler the scroll is disable and I can't scroll anything

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: No, I have already found a solution and write post below with correct answer. I have the problem with swipeRefresh and that's why my recycler can't scroll

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have already found solution and what is wrongs with my code.  It's work code, maybe someone have the same issue.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/friendSwipeToRefresh">
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/noFriendsTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/no_friends_title"/>
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBarGetFriends"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mainFriendsRelative"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/marginTopSmall"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/marginTopSmall"
            android:visibility="invisible">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paddingStart"
                android:id="@+id/lastConversationTitle"
                android:text="@string/friends_important_title"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lastChatFriendsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lastConversationTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopSmall"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paddingStart"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lastChatFriendsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopSmall"
                android:id="@+id/allFriendsTitle"
                android:text="@string/friends_all"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/friendsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopSmall"
                android:layout_below="@+id/allFriendsTitle" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Fragment

```
private void setLastConversationFriendsRecycler(RecyclerView lastConversationRecyclerView, List<Edge<Friends>> friends){
    lastConversationList.addAll(friends);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    lastConversationRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    lastConversationRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    lastConversationRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    lastConversationAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), lastConversationList, lastConversationRecyclerView);
    lastConversationRecyclerView.setAdapter(lastConversationAdapter);
}

private void setFriendsRecycler(RecyclerView friendsRecyclerView, List<Edge<Friends>> friends){
    friendsList.addAll(friends);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    friendsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    friendsRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    friendsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    friendsAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), friendsList, friendsRecyclerView);
    friendsAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(friendsListener);
    friendsRecyclerView.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I did not need the `SwipeRefreshLayout` or the fragment extra settings to scroll both `recycleview` together. Only the xml `NestedScrollView`. Thank you.

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much! This line of code setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) disables nested scroll when there are more than one RecyclerViews inside layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution:

```
studentsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_students);
studentsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
studentsRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // this line prevents nested scrolling, you can set it to true / false depending on you want nested scroll or not
studentsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```